# Deploying Node.js, express, knex app on Heroku - Unhandled rejection Error: Pool is destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, knex.js

Super big noob here only started coding 4 weeks ago so I apologize if this question is incredibly ignorant.

I am deploying this small node.js express and knex web app on Heroku.  Everything runs well locally. I have created the app successfully from the command line, and all the pages render. I have created the PostgreSQL database on Heroku, and I have successfully performed the migrations so that my tables are all set up. However, when I try to submit a form, which is suppose to insert data into the database, I keep getting the following error in the logs:

> 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360120+00:00 app[web.1]: Unhandled rejection Error: Pool is destroyed 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360123+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.acquire (/app/node_modules/pool2/lib/pool.js:162:12) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360124+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:268:29 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360126+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360127+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:264:21) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360131+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:188:47 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360132+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360134+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:187:35 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360133+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360135+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360132+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360134+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360136+00:00 app[web.1]: at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:41:44) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360136+00:00 app[web.1]: at Runner.ensureConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:186:39) 2017-06-25T06:01:57.360137+00:00 app[web.1]: at QueryBuilder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:32:43)

I've gone through the tutorial on Heroku, and read through their node documentation.  I don't have a Procfile set up because as I understand from my reading it's not necessary.

Here is my Knex config:

```
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL + '?ssl=true',
    debug: true,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './db/migrations',
      tableName: 'migrations'
    }
  }
```

Here is my server.js:

```
"use strict";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config();

const PORT        = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const ENV         = process.env.ENV || "development";
const express     = require("express");
const bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
const sass        = require("node-sass-middleware");
const app         = express();
var pg = require('pg');


const knexConfig  = require("./knexfile");
const knex        = require("knex")(knexConfig[ENV]);
const morgan      = require('morgan');
const knexLogger  = require('knex-logger');

// Seperated Routes for each Resource
const pollRoutes  = require("./routes/poll");
const voteRoutes  = require("./routes/vote");
const administrativeRoutes = require("./routes/administrative");
const dbHelper    = require("./lib/dbHelper")(knex);


app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(knexLogger(knex));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/styles", sass({
  src: __dirname + "/styles",
  dest: __dirname + "/public/styles",
  debug: true,
  outputStyle: 'expanded'
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/create");
});
app.get("/error", (req, res) => {
  res.render('error');
});

// Mount all resource routes
app.use("/create", pollRoutes(dbHelper, process.env));
app.use("/vote", voteRoutes(dbHelper, process.env));
app.use("/administrative", administrativeRoutes(dbHelper));

// Home page

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Example app listening on port " + PORT);
});
```

Again, any help is much appreciated. I used to work as an illustrator before I began learning this stuff, I'm happy to draw a portrait for whoever helps me solves this problem <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `const ENV = process.env.ENV || "development";` is continually resolving to  "development," which is going to be undefined when you push to production.  This is because of your conditional statement that you placed on top of your server.js.

Change this to:

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
```

You can `console.log` your `knex` and `ENV` constants to debug them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually managed to resolve the issue and came back to add an answer to my issue, but I must have not posed the answer properly. I actually just had to set a Heroku config var: `heroku config:set ENV=production` and my databased was connected just like that. But you are right, it was a problem with the ENV not being set properly.